# MediaRecorder's Webm blobs produce a broken video

Tags: base64, elixir, webm, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to emit `webm` `Blob`s (Base64-encoded and generated by `MediaRecorder`) to my Phoenix backend via WS, where I Base64-decode them and append them to a file. What I end up with is a defective webm video, I can see the first frame when I open it in a player, but it's somewhat pixelated, the colors are off etc. The video length doesn't exist and when I try to diagnose the errors with `ffmpeg`, it says:

```
[h264 @ 0x7fcbd3804200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fcbd3804200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7fcbd3804200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
(repeated many times)
```

I'm not sure where I'm making an error (or if I'm making one), here's my short client-side code:

```
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio:true, video: true });
const options = {
  audioBitsPerSecond: 128000,
  videoBitsPerSecond: 2500000,
  mimeType: 'video/webm'
}
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream,options);
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = ((e) => {
  var reader = new window.FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.data);
  reader.onloadend = (() => {
    base64data = reader.result;
    topic.push('video_feed', {data: base64data});
  })
})
mediaRecorder.start(1500);
```

My backend Elixir code responsible for file IO and Base64 decoding:

```
{:ok, io} = File.open("some_file.webm", [:binary, :append]) # This part is triggered once
# Everything below is triggered upon receiving a blob (feed is the base64data object from 
# clientside code above)
"data:video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus;base64," <> base64_bit = feed
decode_res = Base.decode64(base64_bit)
case decode_res do
  :error -> some_error_handling_code
  {:ok, data} -> io |> IO.binwrite(data)
end
{:noreply, state}
```

Am I messing up the file IO somehow ? I'm suspecting that I'm somehow missing some headers or file metadata which media players require.

Comment: What is `io` here? From reading the docs on `binwrite` it seems like if `io` is in unicode mode for some reason you might get the wrong thing written.

Comment: @PawełObrok It's defined a few lines prior (first line of the backend code posted here), it's an `io_device` in binary mode.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, after 2 days of digging and debugging the `webm` files, I realized this was a client-side issue (code-related).

There was a race condition where I closed the socket from clientside right after invoking `mediaRecorder.stop()`. This was a mistake as I forgot that **a final event is always emitted in that case with the remainder of the data** (the chunk between the last emission time and the time of stopping the recorder). That event was never sent as I immediately closed my tab programmatically (wise, I know) so my video was malformed. I had some other code-related issues but none this big.

Make sure that you receive that final event, something along the lines of:

```
topic.push('feed', {data: base64data})
  .receive('ok', () => {
    // MR state will become inactive as soon as you call .stop() method
    if (mediaRecorder.state === 'inactive') {
      x.push('that_was_the_final_chunk', {}).receive('ok' => {
        nowWeCanSafelyTerminate();
      })
    }
  })
}
```